# Translate from Perl to PHP

Tags: php, perl

```
sub numeric_p {
    local($data) = @_;
    if ($data =~ /^-?\d*\.?\d*(e\d|e-\d)?\d*$/) {
        $true;
    } else {
        $false;
    };
}
```

How can I translate this piece of code to `PHP`? The only piece I can't translate is the piece on the 3rd line, starting with `if`.

How can I do that?

Comment: It might not be suitable for your needs but you should check out the [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) method.

Comment: If it's performance critical, use Perl for this kind of stuff. Just general advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a test if `$data` matches the following regular expression. It just becomes a call to [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.preg-match.php) in PHP:

```
// In Perl
if ($data =~ /^-?\d*\.?\d*(e\d|e-\d)?\d*$/) 

// In PHP:
if (preg_match('/^-?\d*\.?\d*(e\d|e-\d)?\d*$/', $data))
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function serves the same purpose as Perl's `=~` operator.